# Getting a job in industrial math with only a Masters?

Tags: career-path, industry

Is it possible to get a job in industrial mathematics with a Masters in math but no work experience and no PhD. Or would one be limited to only nonresearch industrial math jobs?

How about the type of jobs listed here: http://www.siam.org/careers/thinking/solve.php
?

Comment: Would you please explain what's on your mind about a _"job in industrial mathematics"_ and _"nonresearch industrial math jobs"_?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about a non-academical career.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in your question lists many possible job opportunites of what applied mathematicians have. They all look exciting to me (and possibly you) and they are useful to human society.

However, you probably will have some difficulties when you apply for those jobs. There are two things you don't have yet: Math knowledge in depth (you don't have PhD in Math) and domain knowledge (you have no work experience).

For example, *How might disease spread in populated areas in the event of a bioterrorism incident, and how would it be contained?*. Do you have enough Virology background to devise algorithms to simulate this? Do you have enough Math knowledge to solve the math problems behind the algorithms?

Another example, *How can you allocate an investment among various financial instruments to meet a risk/reward trade-off?*. How much do you know about Finance? How much do you know about quantitive finance mathematics?

You need to have at least one of them, either **math in depth** or **domain expertise**. Without either one of them, the best you can do is a research assistant or simply a programmer (to implement the algorithms other scientists  and mathematicians devise).

My advice to you: either pursue a PhD in Applied Math or a masters degree in an area that suits your most interest.

Answer (score 1):

Students with master's degrees an applied mathematics (and statistics, OR, actuarial science, mathematical finance, etc.) often find work in industry doing applied mathematics, but this work is not typically "research" of the sort that results in publications in research journals.   If you want to do publishable research, then complete a PhD.

Answer (score 0):

PhDs are usually preferred for research jobs, since a PhD is literally 3-5 years of training how to do research. However, if you did research during your Masters, you might be considered.